# When i run my web application. I got Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long

Tags: asp.net, web-services

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();xmlDoc.Load(responsedata);
```

It's give exception:
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The Uri string is too long.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043566/invalid-uri-the-uri-string-is-too-long to see if that gives you insight in the problem at hand.

Answer (score 4):

**xmlDoc.Load** expects a URL not the file itsself. That's why it is telling that. It expects a normal URI but you hand it a big file...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.load.aspx

Answer (score 3):

I believe there is an assumption that responsedata holds a value pointing to an xml file to read in, i.e. "c:\temp\sometest.xml".

From your case, however, it appears that the responedata is a stream you received from a Web Service request.  If this is the case, the try the following:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(responsedata);
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Update your code to use the newer XDocument class, and call [XDocument.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).